# C# : Email Tracking By a Beacon Image not working properly in Gmail

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an email engine, I send emails and then read emails view count by embedding a beacon image in my email message body. Whenever email is opened beacon image hits my site URL and I count 1 view from that email opened. But I'm having issue while read view counts in Gmail and Outlook (web clients) etc. like when email comes in the Inbox and user even has not opened his/her email yet(email is still in preview) but my view count goes up to 1...
I want user to open email then I get the view count only...
I'm using C# asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Preview area comes after body tag. Like:

```
<body>
<!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : BEGIN -->
<div style="display:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;font-family: sans-serif;">
    PREVIEW TEXT
</div>
<!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : END -->

... Email Body ....
```

I think you should place your beacon image to bottom of the html after apply above rule.

Also check this link out: https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-preview-text-support

Comment: Thanks @maydinlik for your  reply...actually I'm already adding beacon image in the footer. only issue is image gets hit in Gmail before even opening the email(in preview only).